# SQL Server Agent throws error. SQL Statement works manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-agent

I tried to create an SQL Server Agent Task that executes this command:

```
use PPTEST
Update PPTEST.dbo.T_AUAU
SET PPTEST.dbo.T_AUAU.auaulart = auli.auliart
From PPTEST.dbo.T_AUAU auau
INNER JOIN
    PPTEST.dbo.T_AULI auli
on
    auau.auauaunr = auli.auliaunr
where CONVERT(date, LEFT(auli.timest, 10 )) >= CONVERT(date, getdate()) 
AND CONVERT(time, SUBSTRING(auli.timest, 12, 8 )) > CONVERT(time, DATEADD( hour, -1, getdate()))
AND auli."auliart" NOT  LIKE ''
```

It works fine if I start the Query manually, but the Server Agent throws following exception:

```
Wrong Syntax next to 'auliart' [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)
```

Comment: What is `NOT  LIKE ''` intended to do?

Comment: NOT LIKE '' could be replaced with != ''.  Queries using LIKE generally execute less quickly than those using other operators ( = , !=, < , etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[` and `]` as column separators insted of the quotes (`"`):

```
AND auli.[auliart] NOT  LIKE ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using brackets instead on inverted commas like mentioned below

auli.[auliart]